# Trying to create an array with multiple items In swagger UI

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-php

I'm trying to create an array for Swagger UI with multiple inputs but i don't know how. All I see for the moment is one field in Swagger UI.

**Code:**

```
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     * @SWG\Post(
     *     path="/api/v1/test",
     *     description="tester",
     *     operationId="tester",
     *     produces={"application/json"},
     *     tags={"Test endpoints"},
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *         name="test",
     *         description="Tester",
     *         in="query",
     *         type="array",
     *         items={
     *             "type": "text",
     *         },
     *         collectionFormat="csv",
     *         required=true,
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="test saved"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response=401,
     *         description="test couldn't be save.",
     *     )
     * )
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
     *         items={
     *             "type": "text",
     *         },
```

with

```
     *         @SWG\Items(type="string"),
```

You probably also need to remove extra commas before the `)` closing parentheses.